# What is the iron dagger technique?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was told to use the iron dagger technique to level up my smithing fast  but I don't know what it is

Answer (score 3):

The "iron dagger technique" is pretty much just forging iron daggers because they don't require many components (only 1 iron ingot and 1 leather strap).

This is an old method that used to work pretty well, but it was patched since. Item value is what matters now.

Comment: Which is patched now. You used to be able to max smithing with like 500 daggers. It's still a decent way to level smithing, but not by far as good as it used to be.

Answer (score 2):

The iron dagger technique is used for leveling up smithing a lot faster than you usually would.

Basically, you need a lot of iron and leather stripes. You can also buy the raw leather or iron ore and craft the materials you need, which is cheaper, but takes a bit more time. Then you just craft as many daggers as you can, which will level up your smithing skill extremely fast.

Usually, people take these daggers and minor soulgems and enchant them with "absorb energy", which will increase their value tenfold or even more and increase your enchanting skill too.

Please note that this was patched. It's a good way to level smithing until 60 or 70. After that, smithing jewelry is far better, even if the materials are a bit more difficult to get.